# Tricking / Forcing Enterprise Library and EF to use a different config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, app-config, enterprise-library

I am building a plug-in for another system, which causes it not to use app/exe.config.  I am using Enterprise Library Logging 5.0 and EF5.  How do I let these use a different config file ? I solved the problem for these two tool sets individually, but is there a generic way, should I use another tool which also reads the config files ?

My solution for EF5 is :

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "MyConfig.config";
Configurationn config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,  ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
string connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
MyDbContext c = new MyDbContext(connString );
```

which uses the following custom constructor :

```
public MyDbContext(string nameOrconnectionString)
        : base(nameOrconnectionString)
    {
    }
```

For Enterprise Library 5 :

```
FileConfigurationSource fcs = new FileConfigurationSource("MyConfig.config");
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(fcs);
```

Comment: Have you considered building your entlib config programatically in a bootstrapper?

Comment: No, but even if I could (I dont know how), that would solve it only for EntLib, not EF5 and other tools using app/exe.config

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for :

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"SomeDirectory\blabla.config");
```